# Information on Java/Java EE

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

A common question I get before getting into any new framework. Since we have Java EE with JSP and Servlet concepts we use Spring because it has many packed and better features and it is easy to use.

It provides much of baked and much advanced features which Java EE doesn't provide.

Here I want to know, then why should we learn Java EE what is the specific use of doing so?

From my understanding, we learn Java in order to implement in any web framework or any Java program but why do we need Java EE as we will go with a framework and we will follow it.

If the framework is developed on the basis of Java EE then too we don't have a need to learn Java EE.

If this is still needed, then why and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question can be best answered like this,

See, If ultimately we need to became Programmer some day, if that is our dream then we can learn Java from school time itself, right? why we go to school to learn ABC...Z.

it is because to learn starting point and internals of WORDS.
You can able to read WORDS because you know what does that ALPHABET spells.

Similarly, you can directly go for learning Frameworks, but only thing is it will be difficult for you to know then how internally things are working.

And for you then the framework would be some kind of magic instead of logical thinking and working.

Internally Spring or etc Java EE frameworks use Servlet and JSP as a base.
It only helps you reduce things and the framework writes that expanded form of things internally. But the base is still Servlets and JSP.

So, if you know that when I write one line in Spring say `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` for connecting to a DB then that `XXXXXXXXXXXXX` line internally might be expanding to `Class.forName("driver name");` etc

Comment: Yeah.. but why we need a base understanding when we know that spring is widely approved and we can directly proceed with the framework

Comment: @KnowledgeSeaker: can you just tell me why you where learning "A,B,C,D..." in your school and not directly Poem's? if you have answer for this then you have answer for your Question as well.

Comment: Just a movement if we want to pronounce any word you should know alphabets and their pronouciation . but here the case is different

Comment: hre you ahve got everything what a j2ee has services container , MVA many more in framework it is a start up ... then why we neeed to learn J2ee hope you are getting my point

Comment: I am sorry, I tried my best to explain you, Someone please try. See, Framework make your life easy, that is true but behind the scene framework is taking all pains to give you easiness, if you want to know what pains framework is taking then you should know all basics(SERVLETS, JSP etc). if you are not bothered regarding pains, start learning Frameworks, but I am sure at some point you need to learn basics.

Comment: Really useful. i am getting you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask the question the other way around; Java EE is a fullstack framework that's easier and more powerful to use than Spring for most things.

Why would I still learn about Spring?

The answer is then; in most cases you don't. Just go with Java EE itself.